# Why is an element with 100vh bigger than the screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a div set to 100% height inside my body. The body is set to be 100vh, and I already removed its margin. But somehow my div is still slightly larger than the viewport. Can somebody please help?

Here's an example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check CSS Box model and you will find out :D

Comment: Either `#container { height: calc(100% - 2 * 2px);` or `#container { box-sizing: border-box; }`. In the standard box model both padding and border are added to `height` and `width`.